# Compare Timestamps from columns and remove entries based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = 

Instance       sort_begin             cop_begin          ded_begin
a              04:19:07                04:31:56            04:32:32 
a              04:19:07                02:34:22            02:34:22
f              05:19:07                02:31:26            04:32:32
f              04:19:17                04:35:56            04:34:35
```

The columns are stages in workflow with timestamps in H:M:S format, where cop_begin should begin only after sort_begin, and ded_begin after cop_begin.
However, there are other rows which has wrong values where cop_begin is before sort_begin and ded_begin before cop_begin.

How can we remove such entries in dataframe ?

```
 Output   df = 

    Instance       sort_begin             cop_begin          ded_begin
    a              04:19:07                04:31:56            04:32:32 
    f              04:19:17                04:35:56            04:37:35
```

Comment: Your output shows a row that is not in the input, I'm assuming `04:37:35` is the correct one

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your "*cop_begin should begin only after sort_begin, and ded_begin after cop_begin*" logic:

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with:

```
m1 = df1['cop_begin'].gt(df1['sort_begin'])
m2 = df1['ded_begin'].gt(df1['cop_begin'])

out = df1[(m1&m2)]
```

Output:

```
  Instance sort_begin cop_begin ded_begin
0        a   04:19:07  04:31:56  04:32:32
3        f   04:19:17  04:35:56  04:37:35
```

Intermediates:

```
  Instance sort_begin cop_begin ded_begin     m1     m2  m1&m2
0        a   04:19:07  04:31:56  04:32:32   True   True   True
1        a   04:19:07  02:34:22  02:34:22  False  False  False
2        f   05:19:07  02:31:26  04:32:32  False   True  False
3        f   04:19:17  04:35:56  04:37:35   True   True   True
```

Comment: I get this error..'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'

Comment: @user3555115 if you have leading `0` use all strings: `m1 = df1['cop_begin'].astype(str).gt(df1['sort_begin'].astype(str)) ; m2 = df1['ded_begin'].astype(str).gt(df1['cop_begin'].astype(str))`